# PHP MySQL checking

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bit of an issue with a code I am trying to write:

The purpose of the code is to check if two fields match from a row in a table (the two fields have already been pre-defined in the code, so field1 and field2). If they do match it displays the rest of the information in that row in a HTML table. If the two fields do not match then it echo's a message.

Below is what I've got so far:

```
### Connects to db
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'username';
$dbpass = 'password';
$dbname = 'dbname';
mysql_select_db($dbname);




echo ("<table width=\"580px\" class=\"board\" border=\>


      <form method=\"post\" action=\"check_data.php\">
        <tr>        
          <td>Field1</td>
          <td>
            <input type=\"text\" name=\"f1\" 
        size=\"20\">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Field 2</td>
          <td>
            <input type=\"text\" name=\"f2\" size=\"40\">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align=\"right\">
            <input type=\"submit\" 
          name=\"submit value\" value=\"Check\">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </form>
      </table>")
```

Check_data.php contains:

```
   ### Connects to db
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'username';
    $dbpass = 'password';
    $dbname = 'dbname';
    mysql_select_db($dbname);

         $id = $_POST['f1'];
                 $points = $_POST['f2'];
   ## Query
    $check = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE `field1` = '$f1' AND `field2` = '$f2'";;
mysql_query($check);
echo("<div class=\"successful\">Field 1 and Field 2 match.

$check</div>");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is happening when you run this, and what do you expect to happen that's different?

Comment: My code doesn't work, do you have any ideas what's wrong with it - and how I could fix it.

Comment: Oookay. And in what way does it not work specifically?

Comment: The code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack because you use user-provided data directly. Do look into SQL query security. (Probably not relevant to why your code isn't working, but *very* important)

Comment: Downvoted for not being clear, but I'll undownvote if it is improved. "Doesn't work" is _never_ an acceptable answer to the question "What happens when you run it" -  on any technical forum!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in check_data.php seems incomplete. I'd expect something like:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'username';
$dbpass = 'password';
$dbname = 'dbname';

if (!mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

if (!mysql_select_db($dbname)) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}

$id = $_POST['f1'];
$points = $_POST['f2'];
$check = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE `field1` = '$id' AND `field2` = '$points'";
$res = mysql_query($check);
if (!$res) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

if( mysql_num_rows($res) > 0 ){
    // fields match
} else {
    // fields don't match
}
```

By the way, you should be careful, because this code could lead to SQL injection attacks, as @AndrewLeach pointed out.

Comment: When I go to check_data.php I receive this error: `Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/yoursite/public_html/logantest1/check_data.php on line 14`

Comment: well.. at the beginning of that code you should have configured correctly your database: I updated my answer.

Comment: Furthermore, I suggest you to do an error checking. See example #1 here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Comment: Now I'm getting: `Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/habboxli/public_html/yoursite/check_data.php on line 16`

Comment: add error checking as explained in the link in my last comment to see where's the error

Comment: I updated again my answer with error checking. Now you should be able to address (and hopefully solve) the error.

Comment: Ah, I've got this: Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table WHERE `field1` = '' AND `field2` = ''' at line 1

Comment: @Logan - you should try to do some of your own debugging. If you don't try fixing _any_ of your own problems, you won't learn anything!

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems right. It will return zero rows if there aren't matches, so you can use:

```
if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($check) > 0) {
    //yes, fields match
} else {
    //nop, fields don't match
}
```

If you need data from the match, use like this:

```
$handle = mysql_query($check);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($handle);
if ($result) {
    echo $result['name']; //'name' is one of the table columns
} else {
    //no result
}
```